# Focus doesn't work on textarea triggered by javascript onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple transition thing, where a message says something like "Click here to type" and this is a div which when clicked, hides this div and shows the textarea with a flashing cursor. I have the focus through onload when the page initially loads but I'm after, triggering the focus when wanted.

So I have something like this:

**interface**

```
<div id="message" onclick="showPad();"><span class="message">Click to write</span></div>
<form name="entry">
<textarea id="writingpad" name="writingpad" placeholder="write here"></textarea>
</form>
```

**javascript**

```
<script>
function showPad() {
document.getElementById('message').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('writingpad').style.display = "inline-block";

// this is what I've tried for focus

document.entry.writingpad.focus(); // didn't work
$('#writingpad').live('focus', function() {
// document.entry.input.focus(); possibly redundant
}
$('#writingpad').focus(); // doesn't work
}
</script>
```

**working script**

```
function showPad() {
$('#writingpad').focus();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#message').click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $('#writingpad').css('display', 'inline-block').focus();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="message"><span class="message">Click to write</span></div>
<form name="entry">
  <textarea id="writingpad" name="writingpad" placeholder="write here"></textarea>
</form>
```

**EDIT**

The reason why your version is not working is because you have function that you forget to close it.

```
$('#writingpad').live('focus', function() {
      // document.entry.input.focus(); possibly redundant
}
```

Should be:

```
$('#writingpad').live('focus', function() {
      // document.entry.input.focus(); possibly redundant
});
```

**Check this**:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function showPad() {
    document.getElementById('message').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('writingpad').style.display = "inline-block";

    // this is what I've tried for focus

    document.entry.writingpad.focus(); // didn't work
    $('#writingpad').live('focus', function() {
      // document.entry.input.focus(); possibly redundant
    });
    $('#writingpad').focus(); // doesn't work
}
</script>

<div id="message" onclick="showPad();">
  <span class="message">Click to write</span>
</div>
<form name="entry">
  <textarea id="writingpad" name="writingpad" placeholder="write here"></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: If my version doesn't work according to your post, what could that suggest? Other effects within the same function triggered by the click are working but not the focus. I see that your demo works. And thank you for your answer.

Comment: nevermind it's working, thank you and I like the shorthand

Comment: You're welcome @janicehoplin. :) Seems the `showPad()` function is loaded after your html, so `onclick="showPad()"` can't find the function since it's not yet loaded.

Comment: Actually it is working, pretty much how I had it, I'll post the working script for my case, I don't know why... ?

Answer (score 2):

The focusing in your script works, the issue is with the loading.

Instead of using `onLoad` and live event delegations, you could make sure the script is placed in `<head>` or `<body>`.

Also don't need jQuery for this - pure JS:

```
var message  = document.getElementById('message');
var textarea = document.getElementById("writingpad");

function showPad() {
    message.style.display = "none";
    textarea.style.display = "inline-block";
    textarea.focus();
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4x8qwzmk/)

Comment: @janicehoplin Welcome! If you can exclude jQuery, you should. :-)

Comment: Why do you say that? jQuery is not reliable or prone to risk?

Comment: I actually wrote poorly, I was saying that I used onload before but not here.

Comment: @janicehoplin jQuery is great, but it can be an overkill in terms of bloat. It depends on your requirements, but regardless if you pursue solutions with vanilla JS, you can learn how jQuery works which is beneficial in many ways... :-) Check this out: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/